# Applying a custom shape to android listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello i am trying to apply a custom shape and view to my android listview. It works fine when there are enough elements added to the listview that you have to scroll to see all of them. but if there are less than that it looks like this [image]

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
    android:layout_width="333dp"
    android:layout_height="163dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:divider="@color/darkblue"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"></ListView>
```

here is the shape in my drawable

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#2ECC71"
        android:endColor="#2ECC71"
        android:angle="270"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

here is the code implementing the list view

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            String[] listItems = new String[listOfUserIds.size()];

            for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                listItems[i] = users.get(i);
            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(EventDetailsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is what it looks like when there are enough elements to scroll

[image]

Comment: What about the picture is wrong? The line in the middle of the rounded square? The fact that there's a bottom part? I can see the picture but I don't know what part of it you do not like.

Comment: The bottom green block under the name

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like when it looks good? I.e. a screenshot of a filled-up list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave background to the listView, And list view height is `163dp`, so if there are only a few items it will not fill the complete layout. so you are able to see the backgroud. the solution is instead of giving fixed height you can give `wrap_content` or instead of giving background to list, you should give to list item.

Answer (score 0):

Muthukrishnan's answer is technically correct, but it doesn't seem to actually solve the problem of "how can I have a `ListView` with rounded corners?"

As he says, you should remove the background from your `ListView` tag and instead apply a background to your item views. If you do that, you will either (a) have a square list view or (b) have rounded corners on every item.

Unfortunately, there's no great way to provide rounded corners at the `ListView` without providing a background.

The best solution I can think of is to overlay a second `View` on top of your `ListView` and use this view to draw the rounded corners. I used a vector drawable to do this.

Here's a very simple app that shows this in action.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#777">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#00ffffff"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fake_rounded_corners"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**itemview.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="#fff"/>
```

**fake_rounded_corners.xml**

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="333dp"
    android:height="163dp"
    android:viewportWidth="333.0"
    android:viewportHeight="163.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#777"
        android:pathData="M0 7v-7h7a7 7 0 0 0 -7 7"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#777"
        android:pathData="M326 0h7v7a7 7 0 0 0 -7 -7"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#777"
        android:pathData="M333 156v7h-7a7 7 0 0 0 7 -7"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#777"
        android:pathData="M0 156v7h7a7 7 0 0 1 -7 -7"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you